# Python: проблемы с If. При вводе разных ответов получаеться один и тот же вывод

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Короче, я решил сделать простенькую программу которая записывает данные ввода пользователя и выводит их на экран. Для начала я сделал строку, которая будет спрашивать пользователя, начинать ли программу или нет, но при вводе разных ответов выходит один и тот же вывод.

```
message1 = str(input("Начнем создавать пасспорт?: "))
if "yes":
    print("Отлично! начинаем!")
elif "no":
    print("Хочешь не хочешь, а создать пасспорт необходимо. Так что запускаем программу!")
```

А вот вывод программы:

```
Начнем создавать пасспорт?: no
Отлично! начинаем!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
message1 = input("Начнем создавать пасспорт?: ")
if message1 == "yes":                                 # <------ Здесь разница
    print("Отлично! начинаем!")
elif message1 == "no":                                # <------ и здесь
    print("Хочешь не хочешь, а создать пасспорт необходимо. Так что запускаем программу!")
```

---

Объяснение:

1. Первая строка: Не нужно (но возможно) применить функцию `str()` т.к. функция `input()` *всё-таки возвращает строку.*
2. Вторая строка:

   - `if "yes":` *Что* для решения должно быть "yes"? `message1`, конечно.
     Нужно это Питону подсказать: `if message1 == "yes":`
   - *Непустая строка* ( `if "yes":`) всегда вычисляется как *правда* (`True`), *пустая* как *неправда* (`False`). Значит, ветвь `if "что угодно":` *всегда выполнится,* т.е. и ваша `print("Отлично! начинаем!")`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сравниваете введенной значение, а фактически проверяете является ли строка `"yes" == ""` пустой.

Для того чтобы ваш код работал следует сравнивать введенное сообщение:

```
message1 = str(input("Начнем создавать пасспорт?: "))
if message1 == "yes":
    print("Отлично! начинаем!")
elif message1 == "no":
    print("Хочешь не хочешь, а создать пасспорт необходимо. Так что запускаем программу!")
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @MarianD Спасибо за уточнение.

Answer (score -1):

> Надо сравнивать полученное сообщение, в вашем случае вы проверяете является ли строка "yes" == None.  Поэтому надо сказать Питону что с чем сравнивать

```
message1 = str(input("Начнем создавать паспорт?: "))
if message1 == "yes":
    print("Отлично! начинаем!")
elif message1 == "no":
    print("Хочешь не хочешь, а создать паспорт необходимо. Так что запускаем программу!")
```

Comment: TimLi, а чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа @Mazik7512, который был дан на несколько часов раньше? Что он дает автору вопроса или базе знаний? (это комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений").